# When should I interrupt the "Attempting repairs" (aka: when to hard reboot / shutdown)

Tags: windows-10

It has been stuck for 10 minutes, but as I do research about this I found out that it can go on forever, whatever the case may be: either the repairing be triggered via automatic startup, or manually via the installation disk, or "safe mode menu" thing (I don't know the technical name for the last one).

And we all know Microsoft is evil: there's no log showing up, just the black screen with the "dots circle" animation and an overall-mostly-useless message: "Attempting repairs". Not even a percentage of progress.

But what if the attempting is working? If I press the reboot button, does the disk become hardware garbage instantly, or is just Microsoft delaying the possible inevitable failure to access the disk in the first place?

Maybe you guys know from experience, perhaps from any source at all, there has to be a time mark when it starts to attempt all over again, or how much time should it take, so that I can shutdown the computer from the power up button or reboot to try something else.

Comment: one of the possible repair steps is a chkdsk, which can run for long periods of time. I'd give it at least a couple hours. canceling these kinds of repairs could damage your system (it depends entirely on the exact things it was doing when you reboot) so its best to be patient until you can be reasonably sure that you have no other option but to take the risk.

Comment: Keep in mind, when the dots are spinning, it is still actively working. If you go away and come back after 5 hours and still see this, it is possible it has done the following in the meanwhile: attempt repairs, reboot, fail, attempt repairs, reboot, fail, attempt repairs, reboot, fail... etc. Its then stuck in a bootloop.

Comment: I'd always weigh up the urgency of hard rebooting against the time since your last backup. If it was an hour ago, hit the button. Any longer & I'd be more circumspect...

Comment: You should be using an online backup service. That should encourage you to reboot the system, and it will either work or put you to reinstall the operating system as soon as possible, having your files backup ready.